# issue in adding objects in OR

Tags: object, qtp

we are facing a strange issue

on Object spy on an object > all the properties and corresponding values are displayed properly in the Object Spy dialog

but when we add this object in OR no property and values are displayed for this object in OR.

Environment: .NET 4.0, wpf, QTP 11

Pls reply to this query

Regards

Comment: Put your code here,please

Answer (score 0):

Pls find below steps and details:
Scenario: To add Close button in OR. Close button is displayed in a window in the application
There are three levels of hierarchies shown in Object Spy 
Top level (parent): WpfWindow 
Second Level: wpfobject
Third Level: Targetted control 'Close' button

WpfWindow is the window in which Close button is displayed. This window is highlighting properly (via Object Spy) in the application
We are not sure of second object shown in OR. When we try to highlight this object (via OR), error message displayed is ‘Selected Object cannot be found in the application’ and QTP is not adding Close button in OR.
When try to locate this object again, in the application, system hangs

Steps:
1.  Object Spy on Close button > Properties and corresponding values are displayed
2. . Select 2nd level object > Properties and corresponding values are displayed
3.  Select 1st level object (WpfWindow) > Properties and corresponding values are displayed
4. Again select 2nd level object > error message ‘Selected Object cannot be found in the application’ is displayed
5. Again select 3rd level object (Close) > error message ‘Selected Object cannot be found in the application’ is displayed
6. Again select 2nd level object (Search) > No properties and values are displayed. Object SPy is shown blank
7. Again select 3rd level object (Close) > No properties and values are displayed